# May I use MSBuild / Build Tools for Visual Studio to compile projects from command line, without Visual Studio?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2019

From [MSBuild documentation on learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild?view=vs-2019):

> The Microsoft Build Engine is a platform for building applications. This engine, which is also known as MSBuild, provides an XML schema for a project file that controls how the build platform processes and builds software. Visual Studio uses MSBuild, but MSBuild doesn't depend on Visual Studio. By invoking *msbuild.exe* on your project or solution file, you can orchestrate and build products in environments where Visual Studio isn't installed.'
>
> (...)
>
> The following examples illustrate when you might run builds by invoking MSBuild from the command line instead of the Visual Studio IDE.
>
> - Visual Studio isn't installed. ([Download MSBuild without Visual Studio.](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/?q=build%20tools))

OK, so it would seem that MS *wants* people to be able to build projects with MSBuild alone, without the full VisualStudio IDE.

However, when I download MSBuild from the page the documentation linked to, the installer wants me to accept [these license terms](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/license-terms/mlt031519/), which state:

> You may install and use any number of copies of the software to use solely with Visual Studio Community, Visual Studio Professional, and Visual Studio Enterprise, to develop and test your applications.

??? It would seem the license *explicitely forbids me* from doing what the documentation page described! I may not use MSBuild on its own - I must only use it with VisualStudio. So, I imagine, I may only compile a project if I open it with VisualStudio and let VisualStudio invoke MSBuild after I click the green arrow in VisualStudio GUI??

Am I reading the license wrong? Because this seems contrary to what Microsoft seems to intend to allow its customers!

Comment: You just need a VS license and you can use the build tools.

Comment: @sommmen [But I thought msbuild was on MIT license](https://github.com/microsoft/msbuild)

Comment: msbuild is just shipped with vs, if you have a valid license for vs already you can surely use the msbuild tools. you have a license after all.

Comment: When you use something (installers) provided by Microsoft, you might come across such license agreements. MSBuild indeed is open source, but you need to compile it from the source code and then not bounded by any license agreements. An example is that JetBrains has its own MSBuild distribution, https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2018/04/13/introducing-jetbrains-redistributable-msbuild/

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT Not sure what to tell you :) Your answer answers my question (have a vote+accept) but does not solve my problem, likely due to the XY problem on my part. My problem is that I have doubts if I'm entitled to use VS 2019 Community for the task I'm performing now but the client wants the code to be compiled under .Net Framework and not .Net Code (I learned this after I wrote code in VS Code). For practical reasons I have trouble buying VS Professional license in time (need to have the bank give me card, too much time).

Comment: So I was looking for any way to build the code under .Net Framework without using VS IDE. Hoped that MSBuild would save me since I thought it was on MIT license. My problem seems to have solved itself since I learned the client still uses VS 2013 Express, so presumably I need to make sure the code can be compiled by VS 2013 Express so perhaps I should use it as well... and, unless I'm severely mistaken, VS 2013 Express does not have such license restrictions as VS 2019 Community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Am I reading the license wrong? Because this seems contrary to what
>   Microsoft seems to intend to allow its customers!

I think you do not have to worry too much about that. That means `Build Tool` can work with Visual Studio Community, Professional and so on--------you can use this separate build tool to build projects created by VS IDE.

**Besides**, this is one of the rules of use and as long as you satisfy one of the licenses, you can use the Build Tool directly. Also in general, if you have the license to use **VS IDE**(Community, Professional, Enterprise), you could meet the license and use Build Tool directly.

I am sure that the following rules can satisfy you. In fact, the Build Tool is a compilation tool. Compared with **VS IDE**, there are not so many harsh requirements. Basically, users can meet the rules listed in it.

**To use it**, when you finish installing it, you can just open it, it is simply a separate installation of [developer command prompt for VS2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/developer-command-prompt-for-vs). And then type command line to build your project.

Hope it could help you.